# How do I check when CPU or GPU usage exceeds a certain amount for programs on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch, cpu-usage

I am working with Windows and I am wanting to check when the CPU and GPU usage of a program exceeds a certain amountin order to run a batch script. Is there some way I can do this?

Comment: Your not going to be able to do that with a batch script.  It would be tough with PowerShell which is infinitely more capable than a batch script.

Comment: Figure out (process of elimination in your script) what program is using excessive CPU and GPU.  That is how you would approach this problem solving excercise.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to monitor threshold exceeds through batch or shell scripts, but monitoring an individual process and its CPU and GPU usage can be done with Sysinternals Process Explorer: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

You can monitor individual processes over time by doubleclicking said process and switching to the 'GPU graph' tab. Just leave the subwindow open to accumulate a history, drag it to a secondary screen if you have one for monitoring convenience.

[image]

If you're not sure which process is the culprit you can also turn on the GPU column by right mouse clicking the column headers, 'Select columns' and in the 'Process GPU' tab tick 'GPU usage'. If you sort it by that column you'll see which processes are taxing it the most. Pressing the space bar pauses refreshing so you can browse the list (press again to turn it back on).

PS. Process Explorer can replace the standard task manager if you like the additional functionality:
(while running as admin) Options -> Replace task manager

Comment: im trying to use the output of cpu usage to manage scripting, it would be unfeasible for me to take outputs from task manager. How does task manager get its values?